# Swift: 'var' declaration without getter/setter method not allowed here

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried to declare `IBOutlet` property on extension of class. But it give error as

> 'var' declaration without getter/setter method not allowed here

```
class ExampleView : UIView
{

}

extension ExampleView
{
    @IBOutlet var btn1, btn2 : UIButton // here I got error.

}
```

Please any one suggest me correct way to do it?

Comment: Its because you're trying to add a property using an extension.  The Objective-C docs warn about adding properties to existing classes through categories, and I'm guessing the same holds true for Swift. This error can be removed by adding a getter/setter for the properties as seen on page 276 of "The Swift Programming Language" book.

Comment: Depending on iBook size, page number may vary, could you mention topic and chapter? If it's possible, we could add private property with swift, otherwise there's no other way. I think.. How can we code getter/setter with IBOutlet? Is it correct?

Comment: http://old.haxe.org/ref/properties and http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=19190744#post19190744

Comment: Right! I keep forgetting about that... Its in the `Properties` chapter, under `Computed Properties`, and `Shorthand Setter Declarations'.

Comment: @iPatel First link : Is this swift code? there is no key for private or public with swift? could you please check?

Comment: @iPatel SeconLink : this question slightly different with this? Is it possible write getter/setter with IBOutlet?

Comment: thanks @NSArray for your reference. Computed properties only provide getter/setter without storage, ie actually work for some calculation with struct/class. I think, it's little bit different with this.

Answer (score 9):

From `Extensions` -> `Computed Properties` in `The Swift Programming Language`

> NOTE
>
> Extensions can add new computed properties, but they cannot add stored
>   properties, or add property observers to existing properties.

---

Addition in response to twlkyao's comment: Here is my implementation of the `absoluteValue` property of a `Double`

```
extension Double {
    var absoluteValue: Double {
        if self >= 0 {
            return self
        } else {
            return -self
        }
    }
}

// Simple test -> BOTH println() should get called.
var a = -10.0
if (a < 0) {
    println("Smaller than Zero")
}
if (a.absoluteValue > 5) {
    println("Absolute is > 5")
}
```

Comment: Good finding.. This may be a correct answer. Wait I'll check and let you know. Now post your example answer.

Comment: @NSArray Since we can't use extension on stored properties, how to implemented the experiment that is "write an extension for the Double type that adds an absoluteValue property" in the Swift programming book https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1

Comment: I added my implementation of that experiment. You don't need to add a stored property to get the absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-XID_191):

> Extensions in Swift can:
>
> - Add computed properties and computed static properties
> - Define instance methods and type methods
> - Provide new initializers
> - Define subscripts
> - Define and use new nested types

Which means you can't add IBOutlets and other stored properties.
If you really want to cheat, you can create global vars or a bookkeeping object which would allow you to query these vars or the object in order to add those properties (and have them be computed properties).

But it seems like it would go against the best practices. I would only do it if there's absolutely no other way.

Comment: Concept for avoiding Global : IBOutlet property should be used in these class alone, then why we make visible to all other(global)? There's no cheat... What is bookkeeping object?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. I think you're asking why I'm saying you would have to use global vars (since the property should be local to that class' objects) or a bookkeeping object. The thing is: you can't add stored properties with Extensions. From here, I see three things that you can do: Give up on those properties, implement the new properties as accessors to (namespace) global vars, or implement a class to keep track of the correspondence “original instance -> extension var”, and access the vars through that class (the bookkeeping object would be an object of this class).

Comment: @filcab Since we can't use extension on stored properties, how to implemented the experiment that is "write an extension for the Double type that adds an absoluteValue property" in the Swift programming book https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1

Comment: @twlkyao: The extension they ask you to add there doesn't need to add **stored** properties. It just needs a **computed** property. What you have to do is add a property, with an accessor that uses self and does math with it. This can be done just like adding methods to the class.