# In swift, extension NSManagedObjectContext can not be in a separate file?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In Xcode, when I create a new file extends NSManagedObjectContext class, add methods in this extension file, compile the project and there is no problem.

> NSManagedObjectContext+BaseModel.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import CoreDataStack

extension NSManagedObjectContext {

    public func insertObject<T: NSManagedObject>() -> T {
        guard let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(T.modelName(), inManagedObjectContext: self) as? T
        else {
                fatalError("Invalid Core Data Model")
        }

        return object
    }

}
```

However, when I use it in the ViewController.swift, like `context.insertObject()`, the compiler reports an error saying:

```
Value of type 'NSManagedObjectContext' has no member 'insertObject'
```

After searching in StackOverflow, I found a post ["Using extensions in separate .swift file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133297/using-extensions-in-separate-swift-file). As the post author said, the above problem disappeared when I put the extension `NSManagedObjectContext` code in my custom CoreDataStack.swift. But why?? **Should not extension Apple's class be in a separate file??**

Comment: Shouldn't insertObject have a parameter?

Comment: @SantaClaus. No. You can replace it with addObject to differentiate it with the Apple's 'insertObject(object:NSManagedObject)'.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, your extension (in a separate Swift file) works just fine for me. Perhaps the "Target Membership" checkbox is not set for the file?

Comment: @MartinR, yes, there is no problem not using the extension function. You can test it by the following steps:
1. In a ViewController.swift declare a variable
`let context: NSManagedObjectContext!`
2. Then call the extension method defined in the extension file
`context.insertObject()`

Compile the project, Xcode will report an error this time.

Comment: That is essentially what I did: `let context = self.managedObjectContext` followed by `let e : Event = context.insertObject()`. `Event` is the Core Data entity. Compiles, runs and works as expected.

Comment: ⊙﹏⊙b汗...that is impossible...do you copy the code I paste above in your NSManagedObjectContext extension separate file? (╯-╰)/

Comment: Yes, I did. To make it compile in a boilerplate Core Data app, I removed the `import CoreDataStack` statement and replaced `T.modelName()` by `String(T)`.

Comment: (Unrelated to your concrete problem here, but you might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109268/how-can-i-create-instances-of-managed-object-subclasses-in-a-nsmanagedobject-swi, where generic extension methods of `NSManagedObject` are shown to create instances.)

Comment: Is it convenient to  share your test code? My code is our company's project, so it is not convenient to share...<(￣▽￣)> Thanks in advance for your warm-heartedness.

Comment: I have just created a standard Master-Detail Application in Xcode (with Core Data selected), and then added your code with the modifications mentioned in above comments ...

Comment: yeah, I understand what you mean. Thank you sincerely！Just now I searched the Google and found [an article](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/04/22/3-nuances-of-swift-extensions/), and I suspected whether it was the access control of my extension ?